# How to color punctuation marks with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to color all punctuation marks in an HTML `<article>`. Say the text is black and I want to make `. , ! ? ( ) { } # @ $` (and some other characters) to be red. Since it's not possible to do this with CSS alone, I tried to make a simple function to change every occurrence of that punctuation mark to a colored span:

```html
This is! the, text. 
=>
This is<span style="color:red">!</span> the<span style="color:red">,</span> text<span style="color:red">.</span>
```

Here is the code for it:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("article p")].map(
    (el) =>
        (el.innerHTML = el.outerText.replace(
        /([.,?(){}@#$%=<>&';’])/g,
        "<span style='color:red'>$1</span>"
     ))
);
```

The problem is that the current code removes all other `<span>`s and `<code>`s inside the text. I tried to use `outerHTML`, `outerText`, `textContent`, `innerHTML`, `innerText`, but each of them have different problems.

Can you please say how I can do this properly?

Comment: Don't use regex on a whole `<p>`'s innerHTML, which might contain any number of tags that would be picked up by your pattern and destroyed--loop over only text elements to modify their contents, so you can be assured there are no child tags in there. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61198587/6243352) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59582082/6243352).

Comment: Thank you so much for the links. I'm gonna close this since it's a duplicate of that.